# Error with dplyr::slice() - env must be an environment

Tags: r, dplyr, rlang

**Brief description of the problem**

I have an R script that is sourcing a custom function.  The custom function contains a loop that manipulates a data frame and returns the manipulated version of the data frame.  I am using the `slice()` function to select particular rows of the data frame e.g.

```
test_alpha_1 <- as.data.frame(TCR_chains) %>%
                        slice(row_inner) %>% 
                        select(TRAV, TRAJ, TRAC, CDR3alpha, CDR3alpha_nt) %>% 
                        as.character()
```

`row_inner` is a numeric

My code works completely fine when I run it locally on my computer and also when I run it on the head node of the server, but when I run it in a pipeline, I get the following error.  However this error only occurs for 9/12 of my samples:

```
Error: `env` must be an environment
Backtrace:
     █
  1. ├─rmarkdown::render(...)
  2. │ └─knitr::knit(knit_input, knit_output, envir = envir, quiet = quiet)
  3. │   └─knitr:::process_file(text, output)
  4. │     ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
  5. │     ├─knitr:::process_group(group)
  6. │     └─knitr:::process_group.block(group)
  7. │       └─knitr:::call_block(x)
  8. │         └─knitr:::block_exec(params)
  9. │           └─knitr:::eng_r(options)
 10. │             ├─knitr:::in_dir(...)
 11. │             └─knitr:::evaluate(...)
 12. │               └─evaluate::evaluate(...)
 13. │                 └─evaluate:::evaluate_call(...)
 14. │                   ├─evaluate:::timing_fn(...)
 15. │                   ├─base:::handle(...)
 16. │                   ├─base::withCallingHandlers(...)
 17. │                   ├─base::withVisible(eval(expr, envir, enclos))
 18. │                   └─base::eval(expr, envir, enclos)
 19. │                     └─base::eval(expr, envir, enclos)
 20. ├─global::alpha_beta_nt_clonotypes(TCR_chains)
 21. │ └─`%>%`(...)
 22. ├─dplyr::select(., TRAV_2, TRAJ_2, TRAC_2, CDR3alpha_2, CDR3alpha_nt_2)
 23. ├─dplyr::slice(., row_inner)
 24. └─dplyr:::slice.data.frame(., row_inner)
 25.   └─dplyr:::slice_rows(.data, ...)
 26.     └─rlang::enquos(...)
 27.       └─rlang:::endots(...)
 28.         └─rlang:::map(...)
 29.           └─base::lapply(.x, .f, ...)
 30.             └─rlang:::FUN(X[[i]], ...)
 31.               └─rlang::splice(...)
Execution halted
```

Looking at the code for the `slice()` function, I have noticed this piece of code within `slice_rows()`:

`mask <- DataMask$new(.data, caller_env())`

I am wondering whether the error may be something to do with the `caller_env()` part.  I am happy to share my scripts privately if it helps.

Many thanks,

Lucy

Conda environment:

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_libgcc_mutex             0.1                 conda_forge    conda-forge
_openmp_mutex             4.5                       1_gnu    conda-forge
_r-mutex                  1.0.1               anacondar_1    conda-forge
aiohttp                   3.7.4.post0      py39h3811e60_0    conda-forge
apsw                      3.34.0.r1        py39hf3435bc_0    conda-forge
async-timeout             3.0.1                   py_1000    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
bcrypt                    3.2.0            py39h3811e60_1    conda-forge
binutils_impl_linux-64    2.35.1               h193b22a_2    conda-forge
binutils_linux-64         2.35                h67ddf6f_30    conda-forge
blas                      1.1                    openblas    conda-forge
boto3                     1.17.103           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
botocore                  1.20.103           pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39h3811e60_1001    conda-forge
bwidget                   1.9.14                        0    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.8                h7f98852_4    conda-forge
c-ares                    1.17.1               h7f98852_1    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.5.30            ha878542_0    conda-forge
cachetools                4.2.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
cairo                     1.16.0            h6cf1ce9_1008    conda-forge
certifi                   2021.5.30        py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.5           py39he32792d_0    conda-forge
cgatcore                  0.6.7                      py_0    bioconda
chardet                   4.0.0            py39hf3d152e_1    conda-forge
coreutils                 8.32                 h7b6447c_0  
cryptography              3.4.7            py39hbca0aa6_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.77.0               hea6ffbf_0    conda-forge
drmaa                     0.7.9                   py_1000    conda-forge
font-ttf-dejavu-sans-mono 2.37                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-inconsolata      3.000                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-source-code-pro  2.038                h77eed37_0    conda-forge
font-ttf-ubuntu           0.83                 hab24e00_0    conda-forge
fontconfig                2.13.1            hba837de_1005    conda-forge
fonts-conda-ecosystem     1                             0    conda-forge
fonts-conda-forge         1                             0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h0708190_1    conda-forge
fribidi                   1.0.10               h516909a_0    conda-forge
ftputil                   5.0.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
gcc_impl_linux-64         9.3.0               h70c0ae5_19    conda-forge
gcc_linux-64              9.3.0               hf25ea35_30    conda-forge
gettext                   0.21.0               hf68c758_0  
gevent                    21.1.2           py39h3811e60_0    conda-forge
gfortran_impl_linux-64    9.3.0               hc4a2995_19    conda-forge
gfortran_linux-64         9.3.0               hdc58fab_30    conda-forge
google-api-core           1.30.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
google-auth               1.32.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-core         1.7.1              pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-sdk          347.0.0          py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
google-cloud-storage      1.39.0             pyhd3eb1b0_0  
google-crc32c             1.1.2            py39hb81f231_0    conda-forge
google-resumable-media    1.3.1              pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
googleapis-common-protos  1.53.0           py39hf3d152e_0    conda-forge
graphite2                 1.3.14               h23475e2_0  
greenlet                  1.1.0            py39he80948d_0    conda-forge
grpcio                    1.38.1           py39hff7568b_0    conda-forge
gsl                       2.6                  he838d99_2    conda-forge
gxx_impl_linux-64         9.3.0               hd87eabc_19    conda-forge
gxx_linux-64              9.3.0               h3fbe746_30    conda-forge
harfbuzz                  2.8.1                h83ec7ef_0    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h58526e2_0    conda-forge
idna                      2.10               pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jbig                      2.1               h7f98852_2003    conda-forge
jmespath                  0.10.0             pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h516909a_0    conda-forge
kernel-headers_linux-64   2.6.32              h77966d4_13    conda-forge
krb5                      1.19.1               hcc1bbae_0    conda-forge
ld_impl_linux-64          2.35.1               hea4e1c9_2    conda-forge
lerc                      2.2.1                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libcrc32c                 1.1.1                he1b5a44_2    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.77.0               h2574ce0_0    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.7                  h7f98852_5    conda-forge
libedit                   3.1.20210216         h27cfd23_1  
libev                     4.33                 h516909a_1    conda-forge
libffi                    3.3                  h58526e2_2    conda-forge
libgcc-devel_linux-64     9.3.0               h7864c58_19    conda-forge
libgcc-ng                 9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libgfortran-ng            9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libgfortran5              9.3.0               hff62375_19    conda-forge
libglib                   2.68.3               h3e27bee_0    conda-forge
libgomp                   9.3.0               h2828fa1_19    conda-forge
libiconv                  1.16                 h516909a_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0                9_openblas    conda-forge
libnghttp2                1.43.0               h812cca2_0    conda-forge
libopenblas               0.3.15          pthreads_h8fe5266_1    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               hed695b0_2    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.17.2               h780b84a_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h516909a_1    conda-forge
libssh2                   1.9.0                ha56f1ee_6    conda-forge
libstdcxx-devel_linux-64  9.3.0               hb016644_19    conda-forge
libstdcxx-ng              9.3.0               h6de172a_19    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.3.0                hf544144_1    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.32.1            h14c3975_1000    conda-forge
libuv                     1.41.0               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.0                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
libxcb                    1.14                 h7b6447c_0  
libxml2                   2.9.12               h72842e0_0    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
make                      4.3                  hd18ef5c_1    conda-forge
multidict                 5.1.0            py39h3811e60_1    conda-forge
ncurses                   6.2                  h58526e2_4    conda-forge
nomkl                     3.0                           0  
numpy                     1.21.0           py39hdbf815f_0    conda-forge
openblas                  0.3.15          pthreads_h4748800_1    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1k               h7f98852_0    conda-forge
packaging                 20.9               pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.2.5            py39hde0f152_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.14.0.3             h7f98852_0    conda-forge
pango                     1.48.6               hb8ff022_0    conda-forge
paramiko                  2.7.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pcre                      8.45                 h9c3ff4c_0    conda-forge
pcre2                     10.36                h032f7d1_1    conda-forge
pip                       21.1.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pixman                    0.40.0               h36c2ea0_0    conda-forge
protobuf                  3.17.2           py39he80948d_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.8                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.8                      py_0  
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pynacl                    1.4.0            py39h3811e60_2    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 20.0.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pysftp                    0.2.9                      py_1    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39hf3d152e_3    conda-forge
python                    3.9.5           h49503c6_0_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.1                      py_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyu2f                     0.1.5              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyyaml                    5.4.1            py39h3811e60_0    conda-forge
r-askpass                 1.1               r41hcfec24a_2    conda-forge
r-assertthat              0.2.1             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-backports               1.2.1             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-base                    4.1.0                h9e01966_1    conda-forge
r-base64enc               0.1_3           r41hcfec24a_1004    conda-forge
r-blob                    1.2.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-brio                    1.1.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-broom                   0.7.8             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-callr                   3.7.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-cellranger              1.1.0           r41hc72bb7e_1003    conda-forge
r-cli                     3.0.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-clipr                   0.7.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-colorspace              2.0_2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-cpp11                   0.3.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-crayon                  1.4.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-curl                    4.3.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-data.table              1.14.0            r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-dbi                     1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-dbplyr                  2.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-desc                    1.3.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-diffobj                 0.3.4             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-digest                  0.6.27            r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-dplyr                   1.0.7             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-dtplyr                  1.1.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ellipsis                0.3.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-evaluate                0.14              r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-fansi                   0.4.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-farver                  2.1.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-forcats                 0.5.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-fs                      1.5.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-gargle                  1.1.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-generics                0.1.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ggplot2                 3.3.5             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-glue                    1.4.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-googledrive             1.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-googlesheets4           0.3.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-gtable                  0.3.0             r41hc72bb7e_3    conda-forge
r-haven                   2.4.1             r41h2713e49_0    conda-forge
r-highr                   0.9               r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-hms                     1.1.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-htmltools               0.5.1.1           r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-httr                    1.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-ids                     1.0.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-isoband                 0.2.4             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-jsonlite                1.7.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-knitr                   1.33              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-labeling                0.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-lattice                 0.20_44           r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-lifecycle               1.0.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-lubridate               1.7.10            r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-magrittr                2.0.1             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-markdown                1.1               r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-mass                    7.3_54            r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-matrix                  1.3_4             r41he454529_0    conda-forge
r-mgcv                    1.8_36            r41he454529_0    conda-forge
r-mime                    0.11              r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-modelr                  0.1.8             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-munsell                 0.5.0           r41hc72bb7e_1003    conda-forge
r-nlme                    3.1_152           r41h859d828_0    conda-forge
r-openssl                 1.4.4             r41he36bf35_0    conda-forge
r-pillar                  1.6.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-pkgconfig               2.0.3             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-pkgload                 1.2.1             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-plyr                    1.8.6             r41h03ef668_1    conda-forge
r-praise                  1.0.0           r41hc72bb7e_1004    conda-forge
r-prettyunits             1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-processx                3.5.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-progress                1.2.2             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-ps                      1.6.0             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-purrr                   0.3.4             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-r6                      2.5.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rappdirs                0.3.3             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-rcolorbrewer            1.1_2           r41h785f33e_1003    conda-forge
r-rcpp                    1.0.6             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-readr                   1.4.0             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-readxl                  1.3.1             r41h2713e49_4    conda-forge
r-rematch                 1.0.1           r41hc72bb7e_1003    conda-forge
r-rematch2                2.1.2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-reprex                  2.0.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-reshape2                1.4.4             r41h03ef668_1    conda-forge
r-rlang                   0.4.11            r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-rmarkdown               2.9               r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rprojroot               2.0.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rstudioapi              0.13              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-rvest                   1.0.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-scales                  1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-selectr                 0.4_2             r41hc72bb7e_1    conda-forge
r-stringi                 1.6.2             r41hcabe038_0    conda-forge
r-stringr                 1.4.0             r41hc72bb7e_2    conda-forge
r-sys                     3.4               r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-testthat                3.0.3             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-tibble                  3.1.2             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-tidyr                   1.1.3             r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-tidyselect              1.1.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-tidyverse               1.3.1             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-tinytex                 0.32              r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-utf8                    1.2.1             r41hcfec24a_0    conda-forge
r-uuid                    0.1_4             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-vctrs                   0.3.8             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
r-viridislite             0.4.0             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-waldo                   0.2.5             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-withr                   2.4.2             r41hc72bb7e_0    conda-forge
r-xfun                    0.24              r41h03ef668_0    conda-forge
r-xml2                    1.3.2             r41h03ef668_1    conda-forge
r-yaml                    2.2.1             r41hcfec24a_1    conda-forge
readline                  8.1                  h46c0cb4_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.25.1             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
rsa                       4.7.2              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
ruffus                    2.8.4              pyh864c0ab_1    bioconda
s3transfer                0.4.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sed                       4.8                  he412f7d_0    conda-forge
setuptools                52.0.0           py39h06a4308_0  
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.4.20           py39h3811e60_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.36.0               h9cd32fc_0    conda-forge
sysroot_linux-64          2.12                h77966d4_13    conda-forge
time                      1.8                  h516909a_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.10               hed695b0_1    conda-forge
tktable                   2.10                 hb7b940f_3    conda-forge
typing-extensions         3.10.0.0             hd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
typing_extensions         3.10.0.0           pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2021a                he74cb21_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.6             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.36.2             pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
xorg-kbproto              1.0.7             h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
xorg-libice               1.0.10               h516909a_0    conda-forge
xorg-libsm                1.2.3             hd9c2040_1000    conda-forge
xorg-libx11               1.7.2                h7f98852_0    conda-forge
xorg-libxext              1.3.4                h7f98852_1    conda-forge
xorg-libxrender           0.9.10            h7f98852_1003    conda-forge
xorg-libxt                1.2.1                h7f98852_2    conda-forge
xorg-renderproto          0.11.1            h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xextproto            7.3.0             h14c3975_1002    conda-forge
xorg-xproto               7.0.31            h14c3975_1007    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h516909a_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                h516909a_0    conda-forge
yarl                      1.5.1            py39h07f9747_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h516909a_1010    conda-forge
zope.event                4.5.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
zope.interface            5.4.0            py39h3811e60_0    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.0                ha95c52a_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Using `as.character()` in a pipe looks suspicious to me.  It would be helpful to see you *data* (`TCR_chains`) rather than more of your code.

Comment: To add to what Limey said, you might want to try `%>% purrr::map_df(as.character)` instead of `%>% as.character()`. But indeed, a complete answer would require a glimpse at your dataset.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thank you - as I suspected, it was a problem with the `slice()` function and subsetting the data frame with base R code fixed the issue.  I am still not exactly sure why `slice()` was causing this error.

Comment: Thank you @MrFlick - I am unable to produce a simple reproducible example in this case, as everything seems to be work locally and if I run it on the head node on the server.  It's only when I send it to the compute nodes in a pipeline that it fails.